# webpack alias error when import css file

Tags: css, webpack, alias

I have a webpack alias config like this:

```
'c-assets': path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/')
```

and there is a file in assets directory

```
assets/css/normalize.css
```

when I use "import" to import the css file using alias

```
import "c-assets/css/normalize.css";
```

error occurs:
[image]

but when I use "require" to import the file, it works well:

```
require("c-assets/css/normalize.css")
```

only css files lead to this problem, why?